# ¿Qué es una signatura en Java?

Tags: java

Agregué un método de `translate(dx, dy)` a Point para desplazamientos. Estoy tratando de averiguar qué es una signatura.

Para Wikipedia :

> *La signatura o firma de un método o una función define su entrada y su salida. Incluye por lo menos el nombre de la función o método y el número de sus parámetros. En algunos lenguajes de programación, puede incluir el tipo que devuelve la función o el tipo de sus parámetros.*
>
> *En el caso de un tipo de dato abstracto (TDA), se define signatura como los tipos que utiliza junto con los nombres y perfiles de las operaciones.*
>
> *Por ejemplo, para especificar el TDA de los booleanos se utiliza la siguiente signatura:*
>
> - tipos bool
> - operaciones
> - verdadero : bool
> - falso : bool
> - And : bool x bool -> bool
> - Or : bool x bool -> bool
> - Not : bool -> bool

Para mí, signatura (o firma de tipo, o firma de método) define las entradas y salidas de funciones y métodos.

Una firma puede incluir:

- Parámetros y sus tipos.
- un valor y un tipo de retorno
- Excepciones que pueden ser activadas o recibidas
- información sobre la disponibilidad del método en un programa orientado a objetos (como palabras clave públicas, estáticas o de prototipo).

Por lo tanto, ¿cuál es su firma? ¿Cuáles son las diferentes firmas y posibilidades para este método?

```
class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Point(int px, int py) {
        this.x = px;  // Set the initial value for the class attribute x
        this.y = py;
     }

    public int getx(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public void setx(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int gety(){
        return this.y;
    }

    public void sety(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean isSameAs(Point p1, Point p2){
        if ((p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y)){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public void translate(int dx, int dy){
        this.x = x+dx;
        this.y = y +dy;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point p = new Point();
        p.translate("a", "b");
    }

}
```

Así para mi los parámetros son dos int dx y dy. Como modifica los valores internos. En mi opinión, no hay valor de retorno porque solo modificamos los parámetros de la instancia. Puede haber excepciones pero mientras que probé con translate("a","b") solo visto errores

Comment: Cundo un método lo necesitas llamar varias veces , pero puede llevar diferentes argumentos, se llama signatura. EJ: x(int a), x(int a, int b), es el mismo método. Pero los argumentos son diferentes en uno le pasas 1 y en otro 2. No es la mejor explicación por eso no lo pongo como respuesta. Seguro que alguien te aclarara mejor la duda

Answer (score 2):

La signatura de un método es el conjunto de características o atributos mediante los cuales el compilador los diferencia, necesario en caso de que haya un `@Override` de métodos.

La signatura, básicamente, viene definida por:

- Nombre del método
- Número de argumentos del método
- Orden en el que se declaran los argumentos en cada método
- Tipo de dato de cada argumento

No tiene en cuenta:

- El tipo de retorno, en el caso de que exista
- El modificador de acceso

En tu caso, para el método `translate`:

```
public void translate(int dx, int dy) {}
```

La signatura sería `translate(int, int)`.

Podrías, además, tener métodos como los siguientes:

```
1.- public void translate(String dx, int dy) {}
2.- public void translate(int dx) {}
3.- public String translate(String dx, int dy, boolean dz) {}
```

Cuyas signaturas serían diferentes y el compilador podría identificar:

```
1.- translate(String, int)
2.- translate(int)
3.- translate(String, int, boolean)
```